# How to Cycle through Multiple Matches using CSS Selector?

Tags: css-selectors

I have a CSS Selector which matches all the like buttons on Instagram.
Say there are five posts on the screen, the CSS Selector will return five matches, but I'm not aware of the syntax required to cycle through the items one by one.

```
span.fr66n>button -> Returns 5 matches
```

[Image of Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s6ES.png)

Could anyone please let me know how we can cycle through the matches?

Comment: CSS isn't a scripting language, CSS doesn't have _loops_ or any ability to "cycle" through anything. Are you really asking how to select _specific_ buttons?

Comment: Hi @Dai,
Thank you for your response, sorry if I wasn't specific enough but what I meant to say was is it possible to assign an index to it, like we do with xpaths?
(//span[@attribute='value'])[1]
Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not entirely a scripting language - you CAN cycle through items and assign an index and display that - `CSS counters`.

This is a display only feature - you cannot select an item - except manually via nth-of-type() or nth-child() etc, so if you want to target the selectors you will need js... but if you want to visually render an index associated with a  list of items - **totes possible**

```css
body {
  counter-reset: button;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
}

button::before {
  counter-increment: button;
  content: "Button " counter(button) ": ";
}
```

```html
<p>Using CSS Counters</p>

<button type="button">Click me</button>
<button type="button">Click me</button>
<button type="button">Click me</button>
<button type="button">Click me</button>
<button type="button">Click me</button>
<button type="button">Click me</button>
```